# C++ unmanaged inside winform

Tags: c++, c#, directx10

First: I am using C# and C++ on windows 7.

I have created a basic rendering engine in c++ with directx 10. It works good as a stand alone application. But, when I sending the Form.Handle of a WinForm I want to render inside to the engine it crashes during D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain with the following error:

```
HRESULT: 0x887a0001 (2289696769)
Name: DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL
```

I get the handle from the winform during loading of the form.

```
unsafe {
  void *ptr=m_view.Handle.ToPointer();
  uint v = (uint)ptr;
  lhandle = v.ToString();
};
```

Comment: For better support, also try stackoverflow, this is a good candidate question for that site.

Comment: Can you show your actual D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain/CreateDevice call?

Comment: This is the code that I call in Render::Init(...) : http://pastebin.com/rPw3HNSa

Comment: Where is the window variable coming from in that snippet?

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone It's a parameter in the Render::Init(void *window,const int width,const int height).

Comment: Right, but how does the code in your question connect to it? What are you passing to Init?

Comment: lhandle, lwidth and lheight from my C# winform as a strings via json and tcp to my c++ application. The application is a .exe that I start from my C# form with Process.Start().

Comment: So it's an entirely different process - that could be causing the issue. Perhaps it would work if the C++ app was a dll called from the C# app? I'll see if I can find any more info about this.

Comment: Make your c++ engine a dll or make a CLR wrapper for it, then it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to create a **CHILD** to the parent window, not use the parent window handle directly.